# Post method from client react to server node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am using react(frontEnd) with nodejs (backend), I am trying to send post request from client to sever. .

## Client Side

Here below I sending the request to server, by using axions.
I tried without axions simply calling fetch instead.I tired with adding localhost:5000 and without but I it still not working.

FYI , all the data that I am sending are valid and there are as requested.
[image]

## Server

Here I am trying to handle my request and at least print it to console to verify that my request is as passed valid

[image]

result of prints!!!

[image]

could you please advise regarding the above ?

After adding body-parser:
currently I am getting a undefined object, could you please advise?
[image]

Comment: is `isTransportationCost` only coming as undefined? I feel all of your parameters should arrive as undefined. Also +1 for clean code

Comment: req.body also undefined in here ?

Comment: The whole request, as well as all parameters

Comment: [Images of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) or [exception](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) are not helpful, it would be better to use textual representation instead.

Comment: Agreed, post code/text so it's searchable for people having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try This way

```
const data = {
    name: this.state.additionalCost
};

 axios
      .post(
        '/api/processData',
        data,
        { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } }
      )
      .then(function(result) {
       console.log(result);
      });
```

And use body-parser in express app

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';

app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Comment: I tried , http://i.prntscr.com/5vJ6ijrORx_s5EMydajgdg.png this what I am getting on server side

Comment: did you add bodyParser also ?

Comment: yes, to access my data I should type the following ,req.body.body.addtionalCost

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `JSON.stringify` your data from the react axios request.

Here's an example:

```
const user = {
    name: this.state.name
};

axios.post(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`, { user })
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data);
    }
)
```

For more read [Using Axios with React](https://alligator.io/react/axios-react/).

Answer (score 0):

Set content type in header and check

```
axios.post('url', data, {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
}
```